# how to add a pdf file and view it in a Page based application

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

Actually i want to load a pdf file and view it like similar to page based application.So can anyone suggest me how to do it with sample code.I searched i didnt find any documentation or any sample code.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create eBook type of app. https://github.com/brow/leaves the link example shows how to load pdf file and show. and if you want to add more animation like page curl then refer example here http://blog.steventroughtonsmith.com/2010/02/apples-ibooks-dynamic-page-curl.html

Comment: i want to know whether i can load a pdf file in page based application or not????